# Pointer is not modifying in insert in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

Program for priority queue, I have doubt in pointer, I am passing head to insert but its not modifying in insert, as you can see I am printing the head

- in insert and main
- in insert it is printing something non zero
- and in head it is zero

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    struct node{
        int data;
        int priority;
        struct node* next;
    };
    struct node* getnewnode(int data,int priority){
        struct node* newnode=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        newnode->data=data;
        newnode->next=NULL;
        newnode->priority=priority;
        return newnode;
    }
    void insert(struct node* head,int data,int priority){

        struct node* newnode=getnewnode(data,priority);
        if(head==NULL){
            head=newnode;
            printf("head in insert is %d",head);
            return;
        }

        if(head->priority > newnode->priority){
            newnode->next=head;
            head=newnode;
            return;
        }
        if(head->priority <= newnode->priority ){
            struct node* temp=head;
            while(temp->priority <= newnode->priority ){
                temp=temp->next;
            }
            newnode->next=temp->next;
            temp->next=newnode;
            return;
        }
    }
    int removee(struct node* head){
        if(head==NULL)
            return -1;
        int temp=head->data;
        head=head->next;
        return temp;
    }
    int main(){
        struct node* head=NULL;
        insert(head,3,5);
        printf("\n head in main is %d",head);

    }
```

Comment: Please edit your questionn with more information, including the exact output of the program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`head` in `insert` is local to `insert` function, any modification to it will not effect the `head` in main and will be destroyed once control exits `insert` function.

**Solution:**

You need to pass the pointer of `head` in `main` to `insert`.

Hence your insert will become like below.

```
 void insert(struct node **head,int data,int priority){

    struct node* newnode=getnewnode(data,priority);
    if(*head==NULL){
        *head=newnode;
        printf("head in insert is %d",*head);
        return;
    }

    if((*head)->priority > newnode->priority){
        newnode->next=*head;
        *head=newnode;
        return;
    }
    if((*head)->priority <= newnode->priority ){
        struct node* temp=*head;
        while(temp->priority <= newnode->priority && temp->next != NULL){
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        newnode->next=temp->next;
        temp->next=newnode;
        return;
    }
}
```

and you call `insert` from `main` as below.

```
insert(&head,3,5);
```

Comment: `while(temp->priority <= newnode->priority ){
            temp=temp->next;
        }`This could result in a NULL pointer dereference at the end of the list.

Answer (score 3):

Super-simplified version without any `if()` statements:

---

```
void insert(struct node **head, int data, int priority){

    struct node *newnode = getnewnode(data, priority);

    for( ; *head && (*head)->priority <= newnode->priority; head = &(*head)->next)
        {;}

    newnode->next = *head;
    *head = newnode;

    return;

}
```

---

... if you don't like empty loops, you could add a `if(...) break;`:

---

```
void insert(struct node **head, int data, int priority){

    struct node *newnode = getnewnode(data, priority);

    for( ; *head ; head = &(*head)->next) {
        if( (*head)->priority > newnode->priority) break;
        }

    newnode->next = *head;
    *head = newnode;

    return;

}
```

Comment: Or, again avoiding empty loop bodies: `while (*head != NULL && (*head)->priority <= newnode->priority) { head = &(*head)->next; }` — which also avoids a break.

Comment: Anything goes... It is a matter of style. Personally,I prefer to keep the *loop machinery*  `(init;test;increment)` on one line. The rest (*business logic*)  can be placed into the loop body.