# Priority queue not inserting element in ascending order

Tags: c, data-structures, queue

This is the code of priority queue using linked list 
i have two doubts in this code

1)   This code is  part of my insert function

```
 if((*addofhead)->priority <= newnode->priority ){
    struct node* temp=*addofhead;
    while(temp->next!=NULL&&temp->priority <newnode->priority ){
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    newnode->next=temp->next;
    temp->next=newnode;
    return;
   }
```

> why we can not do temp!=NULL in `while` loop instead of `temp->next!=NULL` because `temp!=NULL` will also make loop exit in one more iteration but it is crashing what is the reason of crashing

2)I want to make a priority queue such that the element which has least priority
should be removed first and elements which has same priority then the element will be removed first which was added first
input part from `main` function

```
    insert(&head,3,5);   
    insert(&head,2,2);   

    insert(&head,1,1);   
    insert(&head,7,1);
    insert(&head,11,1);
    insert(&head,8,5);   
    insert(&head,9,5);
```

I am getting output for this  `1 2 11 7 3 8 9` but its output should be `1 7 11 2 3 8 9`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node{
    int data;
    int priority;
    struct node* next;
};
struct node* getnewnode(int data,int priority){
    struct node* newnode=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newnode->data=data;
    newnode->next=NULL;
    newnode->priority=priority;
    return newnode;
}
void insert(struct node** addofhead,int data,int priority){

    struct node* newnode=getnewnode(data,priority);
    if(*addofhead==NULL){
        *addofhead=newnode;
        printf("head in insert is %d",*addofhead);
        return;
    }

    if((*addofhead)->priority > newnode->priority){
        newnode->next=*addofhead;
        *addofhead=newnode;
        return;
    }

    if((*addofhead)->priority <= newnode->priority ){
        struct node* temp=*addofhead;
        while(temp->next!=NULL&&temp->priority <newnode->priority ){
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        newnode->next=temp->next;
        temp->next=newnode;
        return;
    }
}
int removee(struct node** head){
    if(*head==NULL)
        return -1;
    int temp=(*head)->data;
    *head=(*head)->next;
    return temp;
}
int main(){
    struct node* head=NULL;
    insert(&head,3,5);   /// 3
    insert(&head,2,2);   /// 2,3

    insert(&head,1,1);   /// 1,2,3
    insert(&head,7,1);
    insert(&head,11,1);
    insert(&head,8,5);   /// 1,7,2,3
    insert(&head,9,5);
    struct node* temp=head;
    while(temp)
    {
        printf(" %d ",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;

    }
    printf("\n head in main  after insertion is %d",head);

}
```

Comment: (1) If the loop breaks when `temp == NULL`, the assignment `temp->next = newnode;` after the loop is erroneous (as is the prior reference to `temp->next` in the previous assignment).

Comment: Your insert code inserts new equal priority items in reverse order after the first item with that priority. You should make the PQ printing code into a function which takes a tag string (to identify which call it is) and the head pointer, and you should print out both data and priority. And, for pity's sake, end messages in `printf()` statements with newlines — at least in contexts such as  `printf("head in insert is %d",*addofhead);`. And use `%p` to print addresses, casting the corresponding argument to `void *` (because `%p` expects a `void *`). Also, remove `removee()` because it's unused.

Comment: @wildplasser: I agree that [Pointer is not modifying in insert in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52625172/) is a closely related question, albeit asked by a different user.  However, it isn't an exact duplicate; it deals with a precursor problem to the one addressed here.  Why either question gets multiple up-votes is a little mysterious; they're not bad questions, but they're not that good, either.  So, although closely related, I don't think this is a duplicate of that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler How about the `removee()`  typo?

Comment: @wildplasser: The `removee()` function isn't used, so I've ignored it — I deleted it when testing.  I agree that the code is almost certainly by the same person (the same team at least) despite the different SO user names; it is too similar not to be.  Nevertheless, the problems to be resolved are different, so the questions aren't strict duplicates.  This is a corollary or follow-on from the other; this question couldn't be asked until the previous one was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

> why we can not do `temp!=NULL` in while loop instead of `temp->next!=NULL` (?)

Because the line after the loop has `temp->next;` [@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52629399/priority-queue-not-inserting-element-in-ascending-order/52630138#comment92192318_52629399).

The usual goal on marching down a linked list for insertion is to know the pointer of the *previous* node so its `.next` member may be updated.

---

Code has 2 functional problems

Comparing wrong priorities

```
// while(temp->next!=NULL&&temp->priority <newnode->priority ){
while(temp->next!=NULL&&temp->next->priority <newnode->priority ){
//                          ^^^^^^
```

Wrong compare when ==

```
// while(temp->next!=NULL&&temp->next->priority <newnode->priority ){
while(temp->next!=NULL&&temp->next->priority <= newnode->priority ){
//                          ^^^^^^           ^^
```

---

Also use `%p` to print a `void *`, not `"%d"` to print a pointer.

```
// printf("head in insert is %d",*addofhead);
printf("head in insert is %p",(void *) (*addofhead));
```

---

What was very useful to advance this was to create a helper function to print the data.  It was then easy to call it after each insertion to narrow the issues.

```
void pq(const struct node* p) {
  while (p) {
    printf("(data %d,pri %d) ", p->data,  p->priority);
    p = p->next;
  }
  puts("");
}
```

---

I found OP's `insert()` overly complex.  See [@wildplasser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52626660/15168).

Comment: See also [wildplasser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/905902/wildplasser)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52626660/15168) to the related question for a rewrite of `insert`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, that is preferable.